Formula relating propeller torque to lift
I'm trying to find a formulas that relates lift to torque on the rotor shaft. Torque, angular velocity and power are related by the following relationship: $P=\tau \omega$.
I am especially interested in the relationship between the torque on the propeller shaft and the lifting force (not thrust). And how the vectors of these forces change when the position of the propeller in space changes.
I.e., I try to find something like $Lifting Force = f(\tau, attitude, \omega, P, etc.)$
There are some tips in this thread, but it's related to thrust, not lift: Are there equations to match power required to mass for rotorcraft?

This is a rather vague question to a rather complex topic. To answer it adequately, several chapters of a book would be needed. Could you please narrow the scope?

@PeterKämpf I can, but then I’ll have to partially return to the previous question. What I'm really interested in first is the relation between propeller torque (or power) to lifting force. See my edit please.

Since the topics are "helicopter" and "quadcopter", how do you differentiate lift from thrust?

@PeterKämpf I am an amateur in aviation. In my understanding, the forces when changing the position of the propeller change as follows. I want to know the relationship between the lift force and the moment on the propeller shaft. https://ibb.co/RgTWRDC That is, in the vertical case, these forces coincide, but when the tilt changes, the total force breaks down into projections.

Wouldn't you agree that it is easier to equate both? Lift/thrust sits perpendicular on the rotor disk (assuming no wind!) and this times sine of the disk inclination can then be considered as horizontal thrust component. If you keep that strange definition, you will have lots of problems, like: When would you do the transition between hover and flight?

@PeterKämpf as I understand it: if the rotor disk is horizontal, then there is only lifting force. To make an aircraft with a propeller move "forward", we need to tilt the rotor disk slightly (for example, copters or helicopters fly tilted slightly forward). At this point, in addition to lifting force, there is also thrust. But this does not change the fact that between the torque on the rotor shaft and the forces (or projections of forces) there must be a relationship that I am looking for. Of course, that this be a convenient tool.

Gliders use the lift of their wings for acceleration and deceleration all the time ... nobody thinks of calling this "thrust".

@PeterKämpf I'm talking about something that is even reflected in these drawings https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2773/1296/files/How_Do_Helicopters_Fly_-_Pilot_Mall_9481f40e-c097-4a4e-af60-1b8804297fe9.png?v=1702573248 https://media.hswstatic.com/eyJidWNrZXQiOiJjb250ZW50Lmhzd3N0YXRpYy5jb20iLCJrZXkiOiJnaWZcL2hlbGljb3B0ZXItZmx5LmdpZiIsImVkaXRzIjp7InJlc2l6ZSI6eyJ3aWR0aCI6MjkwfX19

@PeterKämpf so, can you tell me the formulas that connect "lift", "thrust" and "torque"?

First of all, lift is normally defined as the aerodynamic force component orthogonal to the direction of airflow (which equals the direction of movement in still air) while thrust is reserved for propulsion systems and denotes the resulting force. For helicopters or multicopters, the lift should be equal to the thrust component which is orthogonal to the direction of movement.
The power absorbed by a prop is equal to torque multiplied by angular velocity or thrust multiplied by speed and divided by propeller efficiency.  Here, speed is measured parallel to thrust, so for an airplane propeller this would be flight speed. For helicopters, it should be the speed component through the rotor parallel to thrust. To compute torque in terms of lift, you now need to know the angle between thrust and lift. If we assume horizontal motion in still air, this angle depends on the drag caused by this horizontal motion.
Static hover
Now we need to differentiate between hover and forward flight. Lift equals thrust in hover, but since forward speed is zero, we need a different equation to connect it with power:
$$T_0 = \frac{P\cdot\eta_{Prop}}{\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot T_0}{\pi\cdot d_P^2\cdot\rho}}} = \sqrt[\LARGE{3\:}]{P^2\cdot\eta_{Prop}^2\cdot\pi\cdot \frac{d_P^2}{2}\cdot\rho}$$
What is now missing is the rotational speed of the rotor. If we call this $\omega$, the torque becomes:
$$\tau = \frac{T_0}{\omega} = \frac{\sqrt[\LARGE{3\:}]{P^2\cdot\eta_{Prop}^2\cdot\pi\cdot \frac{d_P^2}{2}\cdot\rho}}{\omega} = \frac{L}{\omega}$$
Forward flight
For an airplane propeller thrust and speed align, so we can write:
$$\tau = \frac{P}{v\cdot\omega}$$
For helicopters we first need to work out the direction of thrust (which depends on flight speed, as drag goes up with its square) and the flow speed through the rotor. This is not trivial and I recommend to write some software following the math explained in the books recommended by @Sophit.
Nomenclature:
$\kern4mm d_p\kern6mm$propeller diameter in m
$\kern4mm L\kern7.5mm$lift force in N
$\kern4mm P\kern7.5mm$Power in Watt
$\kern4mm T\kern7.5mm$thrust in N
$\kern4mm T_0\kern5.5mm$static thrust in N
$\kern4mm v\kern8mm$flow speed
$\kern4mm \eta_{Prop}\kern1mm$propeller efficiency
$\kern4mm \pi\kern8mm$3.14159…
$\kern4mm \rho\kern8mm$air density in kg/m³
$\kern4mm \tau\kern8mm$torque in Nm
$\kern4mm \omega\kern7mm$angular velocity in rad/s


Perhaps the question is trivial

It is not at all, the full explanation can easily fit an entire helicopter aerodynamics book. Let's see if I can fit a proper answer in less space 

The speed $V$ seen by a blade is basically given by the sum of 3 different terms:

the speed due to its rotation around the rotor shaft; this speed varies linearly along the bladespan from 0 at the rotor head to $\omega R$ at the tip, where $\omega$ is the rotating speed and $R$ the bladespan;
the speed at which the whole helicopter is flying;
during its rotation, the blade bumps into the wake shed by the previous blade; and after one complete rotation, it bumps into its own wake; these wakes also modify the local speed seen by the blade.

The sum of these 3 terms gives a total speed seen by the blade that continuously changes in space and time! As a consequence we cannot use for a blade the ubiquitous simple lift equation $L=½ \rho V^2 S C_L$ since there's no way to define one single $V$.
But with a workaround we can use that equation anyway: if the hypothesis is done that the blade is composed by a continuous sequence of adjacent airfoils, then that equation can be locally used for each of these airfoils in the sequence.
So, for each slice of blade that equation can be used to get the local lift (and the local drag); afterward the local lift (and drag) is summed up (integrated) along the bladespan, from the rotor root till the tip, to get the total lift and drag; and finally the total lift and drag is decomposed in 1) a force parallel to the rotor shaft, which is the thrust generated by the rotor; and 2) a force perpendicular to it, which gives the torque needed to make the rotor spin. The following picture shows how the aerodynamic force R=L+D generated upon the "slice of blade" can be decomposed as thrust T and torque P:

Obviously that equation can be used if it is know the local speed $V$ on each slice of blade as given by 1. + 2. + 3. As said:

and 2. are know since $\omega$, $R$ and the helicopter speed are known; these two speeds compose $U$;
the speed $V_i$ due to the wake depends itself on the lift and gives rise to a vicious circle: the lift depends on the wake and the wake depends on the lift! This vicious circle is broken by either using simplified models of the wake and/or wind tunnel measurements and/or CFD simulations.

Let's break the vicious circle via a simplified model. If the simplification is done that:

the helicopter is hovering, i.e. term 2. is null;
the wake in/upon the rotor is constant everywhere, i.e. term 3. has a constant value;
the blades have a hyperbolic twist (this is normally true for a propeller blade, helicopter blades have a more linear twist but using a hyperbolic one the math is easier);
and each airfoil is operating at its $\alpha$ of maximum efficiency i.e. maximum $C_l/C_d$;

then we get that:
$C_T=¼ \frac{N_b c_{tip}}{\pi R} C_{l_{\alpha}} \alpha_{@maxC_l/C_d}$
where:

$N_b$ is the number of blades;
$c_{tip}$ is the chord at the tip of the blade;
$C_{l_{\alpha}}$ is the slope of the airfoil's lift coefficient;
and $\alpha_{@maxC_l/C_d}$ is the airfoil's $\alpha$ for maximum efficiency.


Useful references:

Principles of Helicopter Aerodynamics by J. Gordon Leishman
Helicopter Aerodynamics Volume II by Ray Prouty
Aerodynamics of the Helicopter by Alfred Gessow, Garry C. Myers


Thank you for your answer! I would like to see more clearly the relationship between "lift", "thrust" and "torque", these vectors are shown in the pictures below link1 link2

Those pictures are intended to give a simple scheme for pilots to keep in mind. But technically they are simply wrong... A rotor generates thrust (in exchange of torque), full stop. That thrust can be more or less tilted as needed via the cyclic and collective controls to control the helicopter. This is a much more correct picture of what happens.
